# How to display message box in the center of the screen in windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

The message box always displays in the top of the screen, is there any idea to make the message box to appear in the center of the screen. I have used normal code to display message box, but not worked, is there any option to give the position of the message box, or any coordinate system or postion or margin, that will bring message box in the center of the screen.

Comment: You have to implement your own message box.. Using the popup control for example..

Comment: Yes Pop up control does works, Thanks @RicoSuter